# $\gamma$ is line of curvature $\iff$ $\frac{d\theta}{ds} + \tau = 0$

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I have the following problem in differential geometry.

Suppose $S\in\mathbb R^3$ regular surface, and $\gamma:[0,L]\rightarrow S$ regular curve parametrized by arc-length.
Suppose that $\theta(s)$ is the angle between normal of the curve $n(s)$ and normal of the surface $N(\gamma(s))$.
I need to show that $\gamma$ is line of curvature $\iff$ $\frac{d\theta}{ds} + \tau = 0$ when $\tau$ is curve torsion.

my problem is that I don't know how to caculate $\frac{d\theta}{ds}$.

P.s.
I found [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Geodesic_torsion) that this equality is called *geodesic torsion*

**My attempt:

(Updated solution thanks to @TedShifrin)**

I know that $cos\theta=<n,N>$ and by differentiating this equation I get:
$-sin\theta*\frac{d\theta}{ds} = <n\prime, N> + <n, N\prime>$.
Now using Fernet-serret I get:
$-sin\theta*\frac{d\theta}{ds} = <-\kappa\gamma\prime + \tau b(s), N> + <N\prime, n> = <\kappa\gamma\prime, N> + \tau(s)*sin\theta + <N\prime,n>$ (and this is because I know that the bi-normal is perpendicular to the curve normal).
Also I know that $Sp(\gamma\prime) = k_i \gamma\prime$ because it is line of curvature, and that $<\gamma\prime,N(\gamma)> = 0$ because $\gamma\prime \in TpS$.

Putting all together I get that:
$-sin\theta*\frac{d\theta}{ds} = \tau(s)*sin\theta$ and in case locally we have that $\theta \neq \pi*n$ we can divide by $sin\theta$ and get what we desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: Differentiate $N\cdot n = \cos\theta$.

Comment: This was also my attempt because I know that $cos\theta=<N,n>$ but then I get $-sin\theta*\frac{d\theta}{ds} = <N\prime,n> + <N,n\prime>$ and I don't know how to get reed of $sin\theta$ that is on the left side

Comment: Well, tell me what those terms on the right hand side turn out to be.

Comment: sorry for the confusion,  I've updated my post with my attempt.

Comment: You need to simplify the expression you have. There are two terms you haven't thought about. And you, of course, need to relate $N'$ to the shape operator. (Presumably, at the end, you'll have to consider the case when $\sin\theta=0$ everywhere.)

Comment: I want to say that I can do the following:   
$<\kappa\gamma\prime, N> = <n, N\prime>$    
Maybe by taking basis {$\gamma\prime, n$} for $T_pS$ that are linear independent and then to use the equality that says that for any local chart $X$ we get $<N,X_{uv}> = <N_u,X_v>$ but I feel like I'm not even on the right track

Comment: Well, the equality you "want to say" is true only by accident. You're not thinking about what the symbols mean. Local charts are irrelevant.

Comment: So the right hand side can be written like this: $<N(\gamma(s))*\gamma\prime(s),\gamma(s)\prime>$ so this is actually the shape operator of the form or in particular $S_p(\gamma\prime) * \gamma\prime = \kappa\gamma\prime$ but how can I deal with the left hand side (maybe I done some mistake here)

Comment: What is the inner product of $N(\gamma(s))$ (surface normal) and $\gamma'(s)$? The second term involves $N'$. Write down explicitly how this related to the shape operator.

Comment: I think I got what you meant so I get:   
$<N(\gamma(s)),\gamma\prime> = 0 \rightarrow <N\prime(\gamma(s))*\gamma\prime(s), \gamma\prime> + <N(\gamma(s)),\gamma\prime\prime(s)> = 0$   
So we get that the shape operator on $\gamma\prime$ + the product between the normal to gamma and normal to the surface equal to 0 so this ends the proof (In case I'm right about any of it).   
I assumed that $\gamma(\prime) \in T_pS$ that is perpendicular to the surface normal at any given point on it

Comment: This computation shows that the shape operator computes normal curvature. How does that help with $\langle N',n\rangle$? Have you used all the hypotheses yet?

Comment: So I probably got confused while trying to solve it so I will summarize what I know and hope I'm right.    

First of all, $S_p(\gamma\prime)= -D_{\gamma\prime}(p)*\gamma\prime = \kappa_i*\gamma\prime$. Secondly, $<\gamma\prime,N(\gamma)> = 0$ because $\gamma\prime\in T_pS$   
so turns out that both of this scalar products cancel and I'm left only with the second term that is $\tau(s)*sin\theta$.   
I hope that I got the geometry right this time

Comment: Yup. So you're fine as long as $\sin\theta$ is nonzero or zero on no interval. What if it is zero on an interval?

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot! I finally understood the geometry behind this defenitions, I will update my post with full answer. Secondly, the situation when $sin\theta = 0$ was also something that I've asked myself. Basically I know that $\theta$ is the angle between the surface normal and the normal to the curve, therefore, I have that $\theta = \pi*m$ so we can say that the surface normal and the curve normal are linear dependent ($N = tn$) so I got to the conclusion $N \in TpS$ and that is a little bit problematic, unless I deal with not regular surface (surface with local spikes in it?)

Comment: What makes you think that $n$ is tangent to the surface? Think about a great circle on a sphere, or, indeed, any circle on a sphere. BTW, you might want to download my differential geometry text, linked in my profile.

Comment: Yes, You're absolutely right, it doesn't have to be tangent to the surface.  
The funny fact is that I'm studying from it and from *Do carmo* differential geometry book.   
Maybe I will need to look deeper for better understanding this subject.    
BTW,  Thanks a lot for all your help!